# How can we save a file with date?

Tags: java, file, date

How can we save file with current date?

```
Date date11 = Calendar.getInstance().getTime(); 
DateFormat formatter =new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/yyyy"); 
String date1 =formatter.format(date11);
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("C:\\InjectionExcel"+ date1 +".csv");
```

`date1` given is current date. But this code is not working. Where am I mistaking?

Comment: What is the content of date1 and does it throws any exception?

Comment: I got it was mistaking here DateFormat formatter =new SimpleDateFormat("d.M.yyyy"); Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A file name can't contain any of the following characters in Windows:

```
\ / * ? " < > |
```

Your problem is caused by attempting to use `/` as file name. It will be interpreted as path separator. For example, if the current day is 23 and the directory `C:\InjectionExcel23` does not exist, then you will get something like the following exception (which you should initially have reported in your question!):

> java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the way how you created the today's date is clumsy. You're generating all that unnecessary `Calendar` overhead. Just use `new Date()`.

```
Date date11 = new Date();
```